# Test observable mapping using marbles

Tags: typescript, observable, rxjs-marbles

I have a method that takes an observable as an input and switches to new observable. Alternatively, I could use map instead of switchMap. How can this be tested using marbles?

```
mapFirstToStr(ob: Observable<boolean>): Observable<string> {
   return ob.pipe(
       first(),
       switchMap(val => of(val ? 'A' : 'B'))
   );
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
const source = cold('a', { a: true });
const expected = cold('b', { b: 'B' });
expect(mapFirstToStr(source)).toBeObservable(expected);
```

I get the following error:

> Expected value to equal:
>        [{"frame": 0, "notification": {"error": undefined, "hasValue": true, > "kind": "N", "value": "B"}}]
>
> Received:
>        [{"frame": 0, "notification": {"error": undefined, "hasValue": true, > "kind": "N", "value": "B"}}, {"frame": 0, "notification": {"error": > undefined, "hasValue": false, "kind": "C", "value": undefined}}]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [official docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/first) for the `first` operator:

> If called with no arguments, first emits the first value of the source Observable, then completes.

So, when your `ob` observable emits the first value, the stream immediately completes. From the error log you printed here, you can see that array that was received contains two objects. They are both emitted on the same frame (`0`), and the second one has `notification.kind` value of `C` which means that it is a `C`omplete event.

So, you have to have expected marbles like this: `'(b|)'`.

The one thing that bothers me is that the output values do not match. Based on the two `cold` observables you created, you emit `true` in the `source` observable. When you call `mapFirstToStr(source)`, it gets through `first` operator and then through `switchMap`. Arrow function in `switchMap` returns an observable with the value based on condition in ternary operator. Since the received value is `true`, ternary condition `val ? 'A' : 'B'` returns `'A'`. Thus, the value in `expected` observable can not be `'B'` (which is the value from the error logs), but `'A'`.

So, either you emit the first value `false`:

```
const source = cold('a', { a: false });
const expected = cold('(b|)', { b: 'B' });
expect(mapFirstToStr(source)).toBeObservable(expected);
```

Or you expect `'A'`:

```
const source = cold('a', { a: true });
const expected = cold('(b|)', { b: 'A' });
expect(mapFirstToStr(source)).toBeObservable(expected);
```